# Powershell ISE + vim

Tags: powershell, vim, powershell-ise

Is it possible to make Powershell ISE behave like vim with some vim-like editing mode or plugin?

In netbeans I'm using [jVi](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/), and in Visual Studio I'm using [VsVim](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329), is there something similar for PowerShell ISE?

Or should I drop Powershell ISE altogether and just use vim + powershell command line?

Comment: I would like to say that you are comparing apples to oranges. PowerShell ISE is not a text editor it is meant for scripting. It uses Intellisense and tab completion for path, commands, properties, etc.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right. I'm pretty new to PowerShell ISE. I just wanted to be able to do familiar navigating when I'm writing those scripts. Like hjkl and so forth.

Comment: Someone told me once to _just use the damn arrow keys_. Again, they told me .... not you. If this helps here are some [keyboard shortcuts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984298.aspx). A bunch are obivous but it could be useful.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/36991/windows-powershell-vim-keybindings. There is not definitive for what you want but this has been discussed once in the past. Sorry about the answer I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 4):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but the closest I've come to getting vim-like ability while using PS ISE is to [install gvim74 for Windows](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc), and create this function:

```
function vim 
{ 
    if ($args)
    { 
        start-process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vim.exe' $args
    }
    else
    { 
        start-process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vim.exe'
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, ISE does not play nicely with console input, so the best I can get is starting vi in a new PS window. Not perfect, but I get my ability to "vim fileToEdit", which I do A LOT in non-Windows world.

Answer (score 4):

The last weaks i searched for a way to use psISE in combination with vim (i found out its possible but hard for me to code without the ISE-comfort)
In the end i created a function/submenu in the ISE that:

- With a keyboard-shortcut ([AltGr]+[v]) starts vim with the current file and waits for the process to end
- When I'm finished editing in vim and saved the file its removed from the ISE
- And loaded again (bacause in v3 there is no file "refreshing")

`# one-line
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("edit with Vim",{$cur=$psISE.CurrentFile; saps "C:\Program Files (x86)\vim\vim74\gvim.exe" $cur.FullPath -wait; $psise.currentpowershelltab.files.remove($cur); $psISE.currentpowershelltab.files.add($cur.fullpath) },'Ctrl+Alt+v')`

You have to save it first or it will not be removed
(maybe you add the `$psise.CurrentFile.Save()`-function)
(for permanent ISE-changes you have to put it into the $profile...)

*saps --> start-process alias

Answer (score 3):

The best thing I've found is [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the PowerShell and VIM plugin installed. The Powershell plugin used to be a lot worse than ISE, but recently the Intellisense has gotten much cleaner.